# BIOS shows up after several times turning on the laptop

Tags: bios, hardware-failure

A week ago my laptop suddenly turned off. When I powered up it stuck on Bios Screen as shown in the image No.1

[image: Stuck at BIOS boot screen]

When I turned off and on again sometimes I got black screen with no BIOS loading. sometimes it starts with Bios Loading Screen and freezes. when I press "F2" to enter BIOS it showed me "Please wait" and stuck.

At this point I turned it off and on again several times. It showed me 
"NO TPM or TPM has Problem"

[image: "No TPM or TPM has problem" message]

I did some search on web and found that this error was due to the Fan, I changed the fan and TPM issue was solved.

But now  when I shutdown and turn it on. It does not start with one attempt. 
I have to start it several times also I checked the RAM and was working fine.

What I noticed that once the system starts and then when I restart from windows it works fine. but it does not start at one go when I start it from power button :(

How to fix this ? what could be the problem ? Everything works fine once the windows starts.

Answer (score 2):

[BIOS's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) are pieces of low level code that (for all intents and purposes) allow all of your hardware to talk to your OS (Windows in your case), sometimes bugs in the BIOS can cause it to think it's in a faulty state. Other unknown/unseen hardware (the tiniest transistor or capacitor bank out of whack) can/could cause these types of problems too. If you've OK'd your RAM, I'd recommend looking at your PC/Laptop manufacturers website for the latest BIOS as [your's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGApE.jpg) looks circa 2008 revision. Flashing a BIOS these days is usually a painless process and depending on your chipset it can be done in Windows through a GUI based installer. If updating your BIOS doesn't fix the problem, it might be time for an update as depending on how modular your setup is, your only other choice might be to test out the power supply or the CPU itself and make sure that is still working as expected (usually though a 'burn-in' test or if you have the parts a CPU swap).